# create bootable iso from oem windows 7 (recovery media disc) folder

Tags: windows-7, boot, iso-image

I need to create a bootable iso from windows 7 recovery media discs contents that I copied from discs before they went unusable. So my problem is that in two different folder lies my original windows(part1 and part2 in separate folders) that came with my Dell Studio laptop. Now I needed my that original windows so I tried multiple methods to install that original windows on my laptop from those folder those are-

1. used various softwares to convert those two folders into two isos .I could make isos but they are not bootable(I have made bootable iso`s for other os same way so there is not problem in my method). All the softwares fail to make it bootable.
2. Tried to make usb stick bootable by using cmd method and copying discs contents but again it does not boot to os.
3. tried to install through lan but again it does not boots to os to install.
   So in all the methods laptop is not recognising it as bootable but I have copied all the contents from those two recovery discs in those two folders what is missing that it is not booting into os ?

Folder1(contains disc1 contents)

[image]

Folder2(contains disc2 contents)

[image]

Comment: If you have another bootable disc that has windows on it (Vista,W7,W8), make an iso of that disc, then use an iso program to replace the files in the iso with your files in folder one, which is the only bootable disc by the way, disc 2 is just a data disc.

Comment: @Moab good solution ! I thought of same earlier, but how to do it ? it does not seem easy. Do you know any free software?

Comment: I use UltraISO, but not free. This one is free but limited functionality...http://www.winiso.com/products/winiso-free.html

Comment: Actually it is very easy once you know how to use the software.

Comment: I tried your method in 1st comment, but os is not booting using that iso image.

Comment: I tried to replace both windows 7 iso, other laptop`s recovery iso but none of them is working. I used MagicIso. I also loaded boot Image using BOO.MGR file in folder1

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try.  Create your ISO and use this tool to put it onto your USB and make it bootable.  Worth a try - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool

Comment: real problem is in creating right iso

Answer (score 0):

The OEM recovery disks have fixed sizes, they copied the recovery disk into multiple disks. Some of recovery disks won't work if burned into USB sticks, others would work with some problems (especially if there are more than one disk) or would work just fine. The reason of that is the program they use to create the recovery disks. So, it depends on the disks creation to know wither we can use them on a USB or CD/DVD.

Since you've already tried to put them into a bootable USB and didn't work. You can try to burn them into CD/DVD and see if they would work. IF they work fine via CD/DVD, then try to convert the disks into ISO using ImgBurn. Then, use the ISO to make a bootable USB and try it, if doesn't work then you are forced to use the disks.

Other option that you have is to download the same version of Windows 7 that came with the computer, and use the product key that is given on the Windows sticker located at the bottom of the laptop. This will give you a fresh install and a newer version than the recovery version. Then, you can download the drivers from the OEM website and just install them by the order that the OEM suggested. That's what I usually do in your case. I don't actually depend on the recovery disks or partition since they put a lot of botwares and features that I don't need (mostly annoys me) and also it gets old over the time and I have to updated from time to time, which is a long process to do. So doing a fresh install and install the required drivers will save time and effort.

However, since Microsoft deleted the Windows 7 ISO from Digital River downloads, it will be a hard job to find an alternative download link. So, the best way to work with this problem is to upgrade your Windows 7 to 10 using [Windows 10 Update Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), which will give you the ability to download Windows 10 ISO.

For more on how to convert the recovery disks into USB sticks you can [visit this page](http://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/converting-your-dell-windows-reinstallation-dvd-into-a-reinstallation-usb/)

Comment: My problem is there is no windows sticker under my laptop so I have no keys. If I just copy dvd contents to new dvd then pc is not booting to dvd. Actually my problem is I made recovery discs of original windows that came with my pc(those are not working now), I just copied those cd contents to two folders

Comment: @WSS you can get your product key from the system if it is the original OEM system, check this article : http://www.howtogeek.com/206329/how-to-find-your-lost-windows-or-office-product-keys/

Comment: problem is that original windows 7 is not even installed in my laptop currently

Comment: @WSS your only option is to extract the recovery image that you have to get the preinstalled product key from it, because the recovery disk is modified windows installation cd, so you will need to find the largest  file inside that disk (mostly with WIM source type) and then extract the key from it.

Comment: looks Good Idea ! @iSR5 I have found a file named BASE.WIM of type WIM of size about 4 GB

Comment: I could not find product key from WIM file. Can you help ? on opening wim file with 7zip it shows contents  looking like C: drive contents

Comment: @WSS then you've got the right file, extracting the product key from inside that file will be a bit harder, try first to find any .xml file within the extracted files, if you find any .xml file, open it with notepad++ and search for a product key, if you didn't find any .xml nor any product key inside it, then we will use another method to find it.

Comment: @WSS you can also use .WIM image to make a bootable USB from it, but you have to use ImageX through the CMD, since 7zip will only extract certain files, while ImageX will create and burn the full installation files and make it ready to be used.

Comment: @WSS here is a useful link from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj979690(v=winembedded.81).aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38007/discussion-between-wss-and-isr5).